# python django django.shortcuts render is searching for html in wrong directory

Tags: python, django

For me django.shortcuts render is searching for html in wrong directory:

> C:\Users\benra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\blog\home.html

but it should be searching for it where the project is

> C:\Users\benra\django_project\blog\templates\blog

how do I fix this?

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
return render(request, 'blog/home.html')

def about(request):
return render(request, 'blog/about.html')
```

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html')

Comment: You likely misconfigured the template renderer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-an-app-s-template-directory

Comment: Show your TEMPLATES setting.